Tooltip in Material-UI causes child component (DatePicker) to misalign and render at the top-left corner of the screen
I have created a CustomTooltip component, and I am using it in the CustomDateTimeRangePicker over the button.But, this is misaligning the Popover of the datepicker and it is coming in the top-left corner.
Can someone help me with how can we restore the original position of the Date-Time popover.
Screenshot of the date component 
import React from 'react';
import { Tooltip, styled, tooltipClasses } from '@mui/material';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const CustomTooltip = ({ title, children, placement, tooltipStyle = {}, tooltipClassName = '', ...rest }) => {
  const StyledTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }) => <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />)(({ theme }) => ({
    [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
      maxHeight: '370px',
      overflowY: 'auto',
      boxSizing: 'border-box',
      ...tooltipStyle,
    },
  }));
  return (
    <StyledTooltip
      title={title}
      placement={placement ?? 'top'}
      classes={{
        tooltip: tooltipClassName,
      }}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </StyledTooltip>
  );
};

CustomTooltip.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.any,
  children: PropTypes.any,
  placement: PropTypes.string,
  tooltipStyle: PropTypes.object,
  rest: PropTypes.any,
  tooltipClassName: PropTypes.string,
};

export default CustomTooltip;

Below is a part of the CustomDateTimeRangePicker where I am using the CustomToolTip
<CustomTooltip
        title={`${new Date(selectedDateTime?.startTime ?? Date.now()).toLocaleString()} - ${new Date(
          selectedDateTime?.endTime ?? Date.now()
        ).toLocaleString()}`}
      >
        <Button
          variant='outlined'
          aria-describedby={id}
          onClick={handleOpenDatePicker}
          startIcon={<CalendarIcon />}
          endIcon={isPopoverOpen ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDown />}
          sx={{
            border: `0.5px solid ${colors.border.secondary}`,
            borderRadius: '4px',
            textTransform: 'none',
            fontSize: '12px',
            color: colors.text.secondary,
            backgroundColor: colors.background.white,
            height: '34px',
            width: width,
            '&:hover': {
              borderColor: colors.border.primary,
            },
          }}
        >
          {displayText}
        </Button>
      </CustomTooltip>```


Have you done some debugging? e.g. looking at the created code and seeing exactly what CSS is being applied and from where? It sounds like positioning of an absolute element which is not within a positioned ancestor.
